# =default and =delete is a function declaration or a function definition?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

In cppreference, [function declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function), under the section *User-provided functions*. There is a sentence:

> **Declaring a function as defaulted after its first declaration** can provide efficient execution and concise definition while enabling a stable binary interface to an evolving code base.

The main question is `=default` and `=delete` is a function declaration or a function definition?

Shoudn't that be

> **Defining a function as defaulted after its first declaration**?

Comment: Not sure, but I believe they mean separate declaration and then definition as default like in the following example: [example on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b4b4264a267c5b0f) - Oh. The example is very similar to the `struct nontrivial` in the linked page... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The main question is `=default` and `=delete` is a function declaration or a function definition?

As per [[dcl.fct.def.delete]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.fct.def.delete#1) and [[dcl.fct.def.default]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.fct.def.default#1) they are definitions. However definitions are also declarations whilst not all declarations are definitions.

> Shouldn't that be
>
> > Defining a function as defaulted after its first declaration?

As per above both 'declaring' and 'defining' are formally correct, but indeed, using 'defining' could arguably be more non-formally precise.

Finally note that there is key difference between explicitly deleted and explicitly defaulted functions in the context of this question: a deleted function shall be the *first* declaration of the function (except for deleting explicit specializations of function templates - deletion should be at the first declaration of the specialization), meaning you cannot declare a function and later delete it, say, at its definition local to a translation unit; as per [[dcl.fct.def.delete]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.fct.def.delete#4):

> A deleted function is implicitly an inline function ([dcl.inline]).
>
> [Note 2: The one-definition rule ([basic.def.odr]) applies to deleted
> definitions. — end note]
>
> A deleted definition of a function shall be the first declaration of
> the function or, for an explicit specialization of a function
> template, the first declaration of that specialization. An implicitly
> declared allocation or deallocation function ([basic.stc.dynamic])
> shall not be defined as deleted.
>
> [Example 4:
>
> ```
> struct sometype {
>   sometype();
> };
> sometype::sometype() = delete;  // error: not first declaration
> ```
>
> — end example]

Answer (score 1):

Those are definitions. But like most (all?) definitions, they're also declarations.

[`[dcl.fct.def.delete]/1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.delete#def:definition,deleted):

> A *deleted definition* of a function is a function definition whose ...

[`[dcl.fct.def.default]/1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def#default-1):

> A function definition whose *function-body* is of the form `=` `default` `;` is called an explicitly-defaulted definition ...