# definition of implicit copy constructor is deprecated with default destructor

Tags: c++

The following code gives a warning with Clang:

```cpp
struct Foo {
    ~Foo() = default;
};

Foo test(Foo a) {
    return a;
}
```

```
<source>:2:13: warning: definition of implicit copy constructor for 'Foo' is deprecated because it has a user-declared destructor [-Wdeprecated-copy-with-dtor]
    ~Foo() = default;
    ^
<source>:6:12: note: in implicit copy constructor for 'Foo' first required here
    return a;
           ^
```

As I understand it (see [this question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51863588/warning-definition-of-implicit-copy-constructor-is-deprecated)) this warning is designed to protect against this sort of common mistake:

```
struct Foo {
    char* text;
    ~Foo() {
       delete text;
    }
};

Foo test(Foo a) {
    return a;
}
```

The fact that we have a user-defined destructor is a strong indication that we have some custom resource handling tasks to do, and in this case it's right! We forgot to deal with the pointer so we'll probably get some double free or whatever.

But if I use `= default;` then I'm explicitly *not* doing any custom resource handling.

Is this warning just overly conservative or have I missed something?

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/af19rMGP9)

Comment: You have a *user declared destructor* because you declare it to be `default`. Remove the line and everything will be fine. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75318231/default-and-delete-is-a-function-declaration-or-a-function-definition

Comment: Yes but because it's `default` it can't actually do anything and therefore isn't an indication that I should also have a custom copy constructor.

Comment: *this warning is designed to protect against this sort of common mistake* - No, the warning says that the current behaviour (generating copy related functions implicitly when there's a user-declared destructor) may change in later C++ standard and will then result in an error. Personally, I'd expect standard to take explicitly defaulted case into account if this ever happens, but as far as deprecation statement goes, it's not mentioned there.

Comment: Agreed that `default` cannot do any harm, here. The warning could also be an indication that you should remove the default dtor :-) The use case for `= default` is to generate it *even though it would normally not be generated* i.e. you defined another special. And in that case, the warning would make sense, again.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor `The generation of the implicitly-defined copy constructor is deprecated if T has a user-defined destructor` (since c++11), clang is just following the standard

Comment: Well my actual code has `virtual ~Foo() = default;`, but I removed the `virtual` since it doesn't affect the warning.